# Custom floating toolbar for MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

Is it possible to make a floating (its always there even if you scroll down) custom toolbar on top of every page in **Mediawiki** with following buttons/functions: `"home page"`, `"previous page"`, `"next page"`, `"reload page"`, `"search"`?

Something a bit like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

I'm going to assume that you know how to design the HTML and CSS code for such a toolbar yourself, and you're only interested in adding it to the MediaWiki skin.  For that, you have several options.

- Probably the simplest method would be to edit the skin template file (e.g. skins/MonoBook.php or skins/Vector.php) for your wiki's default skin and just add the appropriate HTML / PHP code there.  You can also examine these files for code examples.  For more information on customizing MediaWiki skins, see the [skinning tutorial](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aSkinning/Tutorial).

  The main down side of this option is that any changes you make to these files will be overwritten whenever you upgrade MediaWiki.  Of course, you could always save a [diff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) of your customizations and reapply it after each upgrade.
- Alternatively, if you just want to inject a bunch of HTML at the end of each page, you can use the [SkinAfterContent](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/SkinAfterContent) hook (either by writing a simple custom [extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aDeveloping_extensions), or even just by attaching the [hook](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks) directly in your LocalSettings.php).  Since you'd presumably be using CSS fixed positioning for your toolbar, it shouldn't matter much exactly *where* in the page HTML it's injected.
- Finally, for skins with the modern [sidebar](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Sidebar) structure (MonoBook, Modern, Vector, etc.), an elegant solution would be to add a custom "portlet" to the sidebar (either using a [SkinBuildSidebar](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/SkinBuildSidebar) hook, or simply by editing [MediaWiki:Sidebar](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aInterface/Sidebar) on your wiki) and style it in your site CSS to look like the toolbar you want.  MediaWiki's own page tabs and top user links are implemented that way, so it's certainly possible.  This would also allow you to move the standard sidebar search box to your new toolbar.

For the specific elements you want in your toolbar, most of the relevant methods should be in the [Skin](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aSkin.php), [Linker](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aLinker.php) and/or [Title](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aTitle.php) classes.  Of course, for the "next" / "previous" page links, you'd first have to decide just what you want those links to *do*; MediaWiki does not feature such a concept by default.